# Bevel edge not the same with cube and cuboi

Tags: bevel

I was using the Bevel tool `Ctrl+b` against to one edge, thing is to a cube, the beveling edge is a quarter of a circle[image]
when i doing with the cuboid, the beveling edge will become quarter of elliptical[image]
Question: How to make cuboid bevel edge same as cube bevel edge?

Thank you

Comment: Apply Scale to the object before beveling (_Ctrl+A > Scale_ in Object mode).

Comment: Thank you very much! @ChristopherBennett